# Implementing Hough transform line detection in 2D coordinate system

Tags: algorithm, math, rust, ascii-art

I want to implement line detection in a simple coordinate system. I roughly followed an article about how to implement [the Hough Transform](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/Houghtransformation/HoughTransform.html), but the results I get are quite far off from what I want.

Given a 3 x 3 matrix like this:

```
X X X
X X X
- - -
```

I want to detect the line starting at `0,0` going to `2,0`. I represent the coordinate system as a simple array of tuples, the first item in the tuple is x, the second is y, the third is the type of the point (canvas or line).

I thought it would be relatively easy to detect the line using Hough, because the edge detection is basically just a binary decision: either the tuple is of type line, or not.

I implemented the following program in Rust:

```
use std::f32;

extern crate nalgebra as na;
use na::DMatrix;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
enum Representation {
   Canvas,
   Line,
}

fn main () {
    let image_width = 3;
    let image_height = 3;

    let grid = vec![
        (0, 0, Representation::Line), (1, 0, Representation::Line), (2, 0, Representation::Line),
        (0, 1, Representation::Canvas), (1, 1, Representation::Canvas), (2, 1, Representation::Canvas),
        (0, 2, Representation::Canvas), (1, 2, Representation::Canvas), (2, 2, Representation::Canvas),
    ];

    //let tmp:f32 = (image_width as f32 * image_width as f32) + (image_height as f32 * image_height as f32);
    let max_line_length = 3;
    let mut accumulator = DMatrix::from_element(180, max_line_length as usize, 0);

    for y in 0..image_height {
        for x in 0..image_width {
            let coords_index = (y * image_width) + x;
            let coords = grid.get(coords_index as usize).unwrap();

            // check if coords is an edge
            if coords.2 == Representation::Line {
                for angle in 0..180 {
                    let r = (x as f32) * (angle as f32).cos() + (y as f32) * (angle as f32).sin();
                    let r_scaled = scale_between(r, 0.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0).round() as u32;

                    accumulator[(angle as usize, r_scaled as usize)] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    let threshold = 3;

    // z = angle
    for z in 0..180 {
        for r in 0..3 {
            let val = accumulator[(z as usize, r as usize)];

            if val < threshold {
                continue;
            }

            let px = (r as f32) * (z as f32).cos();
            let py = (r as f32) * (z as f32).sin();

            let p1_px = px + (max_line_length as f32) * (z as f32).cos();
            let p1_py = py + (max_line_length as f32) * (z as f32).sin();

            let p2_px = px - (max_line_length as f32) * (z as f32).cos();
            let p2_py = px - (max_line_length as f32) * (z as f32).cos();

            println!("Found lines from {}/{} to {}/{}", p1_px.ceil(), p1_py.ceil(), p2_px.ceil(), p2_py.ceil());
        }
    }
}

fn scale_between(unscaled_num: f32, min_allowed: f32, max_allowed: f32, min: f32, max: f32) -> f32 {
    (max_allowed - min_allowed) * (unscaled_num - min) / (max - min) + min_allowed
}
```

The result is something like:

```
Found lines from -1/4 to 1/1
Found lines from 2/4 to 0/0
Found lines from 2/-3 to 0/0
Found lines from -1/4 to 1/1
Found lines from 1/-3 to 0/0
Found lines from 0/4 to 1/1
...
```

Which is actually quite a lot, given that I only want to detect a single line. My implementation clearly is wrong, but I don't know where to look, my maths-fu is not high enough to debug further.

I think the first part, the actual Hough Transform, seems kind of correct, because the linked article says:

> ```
> for each image point p 
> {
>   if (p is part of an edge)
>   {
>     for each possible angle
>     {
>      r = x * cos(angle) + y * sin(angle);
>      houghMatrix[angle][r]++;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

I'm stuck at mapping and filtering, which is according to the article:

> 1. Each point in Hough space is given by angle a and distance r. Using these values, one single point p(x,y) of the line can be calculated by
>      px = r * cos(angle)
>      py = r * sin(angle).
> 2. The maximum length of a line is restricted by sqrt(imagewidth2 + imageheight2).
> 3. The point p, the angle a of the line and the maximum line length 'maxLength' can be used to calculate two other points of the line. The maximum length here ensures that both points to be calculated are lying outside of the actual image, resulting in the fact that if a line is drawn between these two points, the line goes from image border to image border in any case and is never cropped somewhere inside the image.
> 4. These two points p1 and p2 are calculated by:
>      p1_x = px + maxLength * cos(angle);
>      p1_y = py + maxLength * sin(angle);
>      p2_x = px - maxLength * cos(angle);
>      p2_y = py - maxLength * sin(angle);
> 5. ...

**EDIT**

Updated version that takes the image size into account, as suggested by @RaymoAisla

```
use std::f32;

extern crate nalgebra as na;
use na::DMatrix;

fn main () {
    let image_width = 3;
    let image_height = 3;

    let mut grid = DMatrix::from_element(image_width as usize, image_height as usize, 0);
    grid[(0, 0)] = 1;
    grid[(1, 0)] = 1;
    grid[(2, 0)] = 1;

    let accu_width = 7;
    let accu_height = 3;
    let max_line_length = 3;

    let mut accumulator = DMatrix::from_element(accu_width as usize, accu_height as usize, 0);


    for y in 0..image_height {
        for x in 0..image_width {
            let coords = (x, y);
            let is_edge = grid[coords] == 1;

            if !is_edge {
                continue;
            }

            for i in 0..7 {
                let angle = i * 30;

                let r = (x as f32) * (angle as f32).cos() + (y as f32) * (angle as f32).sin();
                let r_scaled = scale_between(r, 0.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0).round() as u32;

                accumulator[(i as usize, r_scaled as usize)] += 1;

                println!("angle: {}, r: {}, r_scaled: {}", angle, r, r_scaled);
            }
        }
    }

    let threshold = 3;

    // z = angle index
    for z in 0..7 {
        for r in 0..3 {
            let val = accumulator[(z as usize, r as usize)];

            if val < threshold {
                continue;
            }

            let px = (r as f32) * (z as f32).cos();
            let py = (r as f32) * (z as f32).sin();

            let p1_px = px + (max_line_length as f32) * (z as f32).cos();
            let p1_py = py + (max_line_length as f32) * (z as f32).sin();

            let p2_px = px - (max_line_length as f32) * (z as f32).cos();
            let p2_py = px - (max_line_length as f32) * (z as f32).cos();

            println!("Found lines from {}/{} to {}/{} - val: {}", p1_px.ceil(), p1_py.ceil(), p2_px.ceil(), p2_py.ceil(), val);
        }
    }
}

fn scale_between(unscaled_num: f32, min_allowed: f32, max_allowed: f32, min: f32, max: f32) -> f32 {
    (max_allowed - min_allowed) * (unscaled_num - min) / (max - min) + min_allowed
}
```

The reported output is now:

```
angle: 0, r: 0, r_scaled: 1
angle: 30, r: 0, r_scaled: 1
angle: 60, r: 0, r_scaled: 1
angle: 90, r: 0, r_scaled: 1
angle: 120, r: 0, r_scaled: 1
angle: 150, r: 0, r_scaled: 1
angle: 180, r: 0, r_scaled: 1
...
Found lines from 3/4 to -1/-1
Found lines from -3/1 to 2/2
```

I plotted the lines on a coordinate system, the lines are very far off from the line that I would expect. I wonder if the conversion back to points is still off.

Comment: With Hough-transforms a lot depends on the actual image and how sharp the edges are. The busier the image the more complex the results of the transform will be. What I would do is generate an image of the output to examine what the is produced.  It might help to add the input and output images to the question.

Comment: One think which seems suspicious is the fact you are rounding the r values quite strongly, with only 4 levels. This will mean you are basically checking with a very wide line, lots of points will contribute to the same line.

Comment: If you actually plot the lines in the output you find they are quite similar lines, some of them are parallel differing by a pixel. By considering a small image you are making life harder for yourself. Try something more like a 100 x 100 image and you will see the results becoming clearer. Try altering the granuallity of r and angle steps to see what happens.

Comment: @Salixalba I also tried with a 30x30 matrix, the results are even with the edited version quite far off unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your angles are in degrees rather than radians!

Rust, like all other programming languages, uses radians for its trigonometry functions. Running

```
let ang_d = 30.0;
let ang_r = ang_d * 3.1415926 / 180.0;
println!("sin(30) {} sin(30*pi/180) {}", (ang_d as f32).sin(), (ang_r as f32).sin());
```

gives the results

```
sin(30) -0.9880316 sin(30*pi/180) 0.5
```

You need to convert all your angles to radians before calling `cos` and `sin`.

In the first loop I've got

```
let angle = (i as f32) * 30.0 * 3.1415926 / 180.0;
let r = (x as f32) * (angle as f32).cos() + (y as f32) * (angle as f32).sin();
```

and in the second where you calculate the points on the lines

```
let ang = (z as f32) * 30.0 * 3.1415926 / 180.0;
let px = (r as f32) * (ang as f32).cos();
let py = (r as f32) * (ang as f32).sin();
let p1_px = px + (max_line_length as f32) * (ang as f32).cos();          
let p1_py = py + (max_line_length as f32) * (ang as f32).sin();
let p2_px = px - (max_line_length as f32) * (ang as f32).cos();
let p2_py = px - (max_line_length as f32) * (ang as f32).cos();
```

My Rust is rusty (actually non-existent) so there is nicer ways of doing the conversion and there should be a constant with the exact value of pi somewhere.

Comment: FYI [online API docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/) are searchable, there are [methods on floating point types to convert to radians](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.to_radians), and there are [values of pi for each type of floating point](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/f64/consts/constant.PI.html).

Comment: [Example](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=18cfdca6a7bd90924f1187dfe50bca48&version=stable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't know that. The results are still not what I want, so I think I have to start over again, the implementation seems kind of wrong all in all. Accepting this answer, as it gave me some guidelines how to work with math functions in general and in rust in specfic, also thanks to @Shepmaster

Comment: I've run a version of the modified of the code which is giving more believable answers. There is a second problem with your r values. Sometimes these go negative, yet the scalling function rounds anything < 1 upto 1.

Comment: @Salixalba hm i thought I implement a scaling function in order to use the values as an offset in the accumulator matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Hough Transform principle is to search all the lines passing through each considered point, and counting these lines occurrences thanks to the accumulator.

However, we cannot determine all these lines because their number is infinite. Moreover the image is discretized, so calculating all lines does not make sense.

And the problem comes from this discretization. The angle discretization needs to be relevant with the image size. Here, calculating the radius for 180 angles is overcalculation, because the image only make 9 pixels, and the possible angles for any line in this image are restricted to a dozen value.

So here, for the first point (0,0), for each angle, the associated radius is r = 0

For the second (1,0), the associated radius is r = cos(angle)

For the third (2,0), the associated radius is r = 2 cos(angle)

With the rounding, numerous values will have an associated radius of 0 for the same angle, and it cause over-detection. Discretization causes a spreading of Hough Accumulator.

So the radius and the angle discretization needs to be calculated depending on the image size. Here, a 30° step, so a 7*3 accumulator will be sufficient to detect a line.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I tried an updated version, it now finds only 2 lines, which makes more sense to me. The issue is however, that both lines are really far off from what I would expect, the program reports lines from `3,4` to `-1,-1` and `-3,1` to `2,2`. I updated the question with my new code, probably the conversion back to points is still off.